# How to pause and resume consumer in bunny

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

Is there any method to temporarily pause a consumer and resume it at later time?

Here is an example of what i want to do:

```
require "bunny"
conn = Bunny.new
conn.start

ch1 = conn.create_channel
publisher = ch.direct('test', :auto_delete => false)

consumer1 = nil
Thread.new do
    ch2 = conn.create_channel(nil, 8) #Using eight worker
    queue1 = ch2.queue('', :exclusive => true)
    queue1.bind(publisher, :routing_key => 'low_priority')
    consumer1 = queue1.subscribe(:block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
       #do some work
    end
end

Thread.new do
    ch3 = conn.create_channel
    queue2 = ch3.queue('', :exclusive => true)
    queue2.bind(publisher, :routing_key => 'high_priority')
    consumer2 = queue2.subscribe(:block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
        consumer1.pause   #pause the other consumer
        #do other things
        consumer1.resume  #resume the consumer
    end
end
#rest of the code
```

I want to pause consumer1 when I'm doing the work at consumer2. Is there any valid way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create priority policies, bunny has implemented this:

http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html#consumer_priorities

```
q = ch.queue("a.queue")
q.subscribe(:manual_ack => true, :arguments => {"x-priority" => 5}) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  # ...
end
q.subscribe(:manual_ack => true, :arguments => {"x-priority" => 2}) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  # ...
end
```

And if you want to process it in parallel I suggest this gem:

https://github.com/grosser/parallel

Example:

```
results = Parallel.map(['a','b','c'], in_processes: 3) { |one_letter| ... }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you provide a synopsis of the two links you provided?  That way the answer is here if the links break in the future.  You can edit your answer to include this information.